# Grafana Prometheus to calculate total downtime on unsuccessful probe_success response, but excluding a one minute downtime

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-operator, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I have a query say (1-probe_success{instance="https://www.google.com"}) - I am basically trying to get a total number of times the instance was down. At the moment it works fine when I set it up as a 'Singlestat' showing 'Total' value on Grafana.

However, what if I want to exclude downtime that's less than one minute? Does Prometheus have allow subquery/condition to achieve this?

My Prometheus is currently set up to scrape data every 15seconds. Ideally I would like to see my total value as **5** in below scenario;

**Sample data within last 2 minutes**

7:00:00AM - 1 (Down)

7:00:15AM - 1 (Down)

7:00:30AM - 1 (Down)

7:00:45AM - 1 (Down)

7:01:00AM - 1 (Down)

7:01:15AM - 0 (Up)

7:01:30AM - 1 (Down)

7:01:45AM - 0 (Up)

7:02:00AM - 0 (Up)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way to express downtime more than one minute is:

```
max_over_time(up[1m])
```

It will show how many times the service was down for more than 1min. By example, for an input series (0 means down) with interval 15s, output series will be `0` only when 0 for 1min (4 consecutive zeroes)

```
input : '1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0'
output: '1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0'
```

If you want to compute the number of times the system was down (i.e. the number of time it switch from 1 to 0), you can use the [changes function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#changes) to compute how many times it switched. Then with a little logic, how many times it was down

```
floor(changes(max_over_time(up[1m])[1d:])/2) + (up == bool 0)
```

If you want to count the time spent in down state, this becomes more complicated because you have to detect the switch from 1 to 0 which count for 1min and the subsequent down state until the first switch back from 0 to 1.

It could be something along the lines of:

```
(max_over_time(up[60s]) == bool 0) * ((up offset 61s == bool 1) * count(up[60s]) OR vector(1))
```

Which will give the number of preceding 0 when switch for more than 1 min and then 1

```
input : '1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0'
output: '0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 1 1'
```

And finally, compute the average of this value on a windows and multiply by the number of seconds in the window:

```
 # downtime for more than 1min other the previous day
 average((...)[1d:]) * 86400
```

Note: I didn't test the expressions, they may require some tinckering